# Raspberry Pi 0 as video player

Tags: pi-zero, video

I use Raspberry pi 3 for this but I'm considering buying a large number of pi0's to loop video. Can the source video be stored on the micro SD card or do you need to transfer it in via the mini-USB? 
Thank

Comment: What's mini-USB?

Comment: The smaller of the two here

https://www.google.com/search?q=mini-usb&sxsrf=ACYBGNQ1rC6TPO84gITulzvD43l5NYUYfw:1568291399363&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnqI3epMvkAhVoH7cAHSZOCFEQ_AUIESgB&biw=1024&bih=490

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the source video can be stored on the micro sd card.

I would recommend using omxplayer on a Pi Zero.